# Interrupts under Windows 7 do not trigger the function

Tags: windows, interrupt, irq

I have some source code with a driver called TVicHW32 and under Windows XP it works fine and the interrupt handler gets called every time there is an interrupt from the ISA bus card. The ISA bus IRQ on 5 is set as reserved in the BIOS.
If I run the exact same code under Windows 7 or even 10, the interrupt handler never gets called. I can see the interrupt line triggering with a scope but the code never gets called. I've even tried to run my code under admin and still the same.
I've emailed the company who supplies the driver but they are not replying. Is there something in Windows 7 or 10 that prevents access to the IRQ? IRQ5 is not used on this computer. This I have confirmed in the Device Manager.
Failing any chance to get a response from the company on this, has anyone got any alternative to handler hardware IRQ under Windows 7?

Comment: Without being able to see the device driver code, it's going to be pretty much impossible to guess what's gone wrong with it.  (I assume you are running the 32-bit version of Windows 7?  A 32-bit device driver won't work on a 64-bit OS.)

Comment: Yes, OS is 32 bit W7 and code and driver are both 32 bit. They do offer a driver for 64 bit. All works fine with XP 32 bit.